# Self Organizing Maps using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, dimensionality-reduction, som, self-organizing-maps

Can anyone help me with python implementation of SOM architecture to run on GPU with minisom or sompy libraries?

Is it possible with these libraries or are there any tensorflow implementation that can work on GPU?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This should work: https://github.com/cgorman/tensorflow-som

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Google yielded this blog post on Towards Data Science, [Self-Organizing Map/Layer in Tensroflow with Interactive Code [ Manual Back Prop with TF ]](https://towardsdatascience.com/self-organizing-map-layer-in-tensroflow-with-interactive-code-manual-back-prop-with-tf-580e0b60a1cc).